# How to post dropdown value in Node.js to MySQL database with EJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

in my Node.js project I have a post function with which I write data into my MySQL database. I would like to have some values as a dropdown on my add page. At the moment I can only write all data with text fields to the MySQL database.

I have already created dropdowns, but with these I can only display the data from the corresponding tables, but the selected value in the post function will not be applied, no matter what I have tried.

GET and POST function:

```
app.get('/add', function(req, res, next) {
    connection.query("SELECT DISTINCT platform_platform FROM platform; SELECT DISTINCT art_art FROM art;", [1, 2], function (error, result, fields) {
        if(error) {
            req.flash('error', error)
            res.render('games/add', {
                data: ''
            })
        } else {

    res.render('games/g-add', {
        data: result[0],
        data1: result[1],
        g_name: '',
        g_status: ''
    })
}
    });
})

app.post('/add', function(req, res, next) {
    req.assert('g_name').notEmpty()
    req.assert('g_status').notEmpty()

    var errors = req.validationErrors()

    if( !errors ) {

        var game = {
            g_name: req.sanitize('g_name').escape().trim(),
            g_status: req.sanitize('g_status').escape().trim()
        }

        connection.query('INSERT INTO games SET ?', game, function(err, result) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(result.length);
            if(err) {
                req.flash('error', err)

                res.render('games/g-add', {
                    g_name: game.g_name,
                    g_status: game.g_status
                })
            } else {
                res.render('games/g-add',  {
                    g_name: '',
                    g_status: ''
                })
            }
        })
    } 
    else {
        var error_msg = ''
        errors.forEach(function(error) {
            error_msg += error_msg + '<br>'
        })
        req.flash('error', error_msg)

        res.render('games/g-add', {
            g_name: req.body.g_name,
            g_status: req.body.g_status
        })
    }
})
```

EJS:

```
<form action="/games/add" method="post">

....

<div class="form-group">
    <h4>Platform</h4>
    <select class="custom-select">
    <% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
        <option>
           <%= data[i].platform_platform %>
        </option>
        <% } %>
    </select>
</div>

....

<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Name:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" value="<%= g_name %>">
</div>

 ....

<input type="submit" value="POST" class="btn btn-danger">
</form>
```

I just know the two dropdowns are not included in the POST function, but I have no idea how to get the selected data to the POST function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add `name` attribute in your `select`. For example:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <h4>Platform</h4>
    <select name="platform" class="custom-select">
    <% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
        <option>
           <%= data[i].platform_platform %>
        </option>
        <% } %>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now in your post function you can access the selected option from the request object.

```
app.post('/add', function(req, res, next) {
    ....
    var platform = req.body.platform;
    ....
})
```

You should do the same in your Name input as it lacks a `name` attribute too.